# Create Inherited Function via Object.create()

Tags: javascript, node.js

suppose that I have this function

```
function test() {
    console.log('test');
}

test.property = 'testProperty';
```

And I want to extend the function object by doing

```
var extend = Object.create(test);
```

Well, the property from the function was correctly propagated

```
console.log(extend.property); // testProperty
```

But I can't extend the function test itself, nor access it via `extend()`

```
extend(); // TypeError: ext is not a function
```

Okay, I can just create new function with modified `__proto__`

```
function extend() {
    console.log('extended!');
}

extend.__proto__ = test;

extend(); // extended!
console.log(extend.property); // testProperty
```

But, editing `__proto__` property is a slow operation, as per this [Javascript MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto). So, is there any function like `Object.create()` that can I use to implement this kind of operation? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to create a function with a custom prototype?

Comment: `__proto__` is deprecated. If at all, use `Object.setPrototypeOf`.

Comment: @Bergi thanks! that is exactly what I was looking for